# Difference between Google.Cloud.Compute.V1 and Google.Apis.Compute.v1

Tags: c#, .net, api, google-cloud-platform

I am new to GCP. I am more into .Net/C# programming. I have a confusion on the different SDK available by GCP for programmatically use different GCP resources.

I  am bit confused on which one to use Google.Cloud.Compute.V1 OR Google.Apis.Compute.v1.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google.Cloud.Compute.V1 is the name of the .net library, while Google.Apis.Compute.v1 is the name of the service endpoint. But they refer to the same service.
If you take a look at the [Google.Cloud.Compute.v1 resource list](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Compute.V1/latest) and [Google.Apis.Compute.v1 reference](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/compute/v1/csharp/latest/namespaceGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Compute_1_1v1.html) you will see the same classes.
You can find more information on that API in this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1).

Comment: So which one should I go for to get the best out of the APIs and considering I will be using .Net/C# in long run also.

Comment: There is no decision to be made. The first one is the library and the second is the endpoint, you need both.